# Can we calculate the mean of a Geometric progression converging to zero?

Tags: sequences-and-series, means, geometric-progressions

I have a GP lets say whose $p^{\text{th}}$ term is defined by $(1/2)^p$. Does it have a limit on its mean considering we are taking into consideration infinitely many terms?

Comment: It's this what you mean (heh): $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1/2+\cdots+1/2^n}n$?

Comment: @Arthur, I mean exactly this. What would be a solution to this?

Comment: Okay, just realised it would be zero, thanks for the help.

Comment: It's a general result that if a sequence $a_n$ has a limit $L$ as $n\to\infty$, then the average of the first $n$ terms will also have limit $L$ as $n\to\infty$.